# How to get windows user and password in Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I wanted to know, if there is a way to just get the Windows username and password in 
Oracle application express(APEX) ?

Or if there way to get them from My domain active directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use `APEX_LDAP` package to perform actions related to LDAP authentication. It allows authenticate, check if user is member of group and so on. You can setup Windows-integrated authentication (SSO). Also read about Oracle Access Control List (ACL).

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_ldap.htm#AEAPI238